# Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting the message “

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in…

in a simple php select statement

```
$wherePtest1 = "postcode= ? AND  proptype = ? AND ";
$whereVtest1 = "$lc_postcode, $proptype";

$where_no_andP = rtrim($wherePtest1, 'AND ');
var_dump($where_no_andP);
var_dump($whereVtest1); 

/* 1. create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT $what_select4TS FROM $table WHERE $where_no_andP ORDER BY rent $reihenach LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage")) 
{
/* 2. bind parameters for markers */
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "ss", $whereVtest1);

/* 3. execute query */
etc
```

I am getting this warning EVEN THOUGH `var_dump()` correctly show

```
string(29) "postcode= ? AND proptype = ?" 
string(9) "da8, Flat"!
```

Comment: Like posted below, see comments for the PHP documentation of this function, for correct usage examples: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: A HUGE thank you to Marc B and Martin for setting me straight. I attempted many things but not the correct one you suggested. Bravo, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "ss", $whereVtest1);
                                           ^^
```

MySQLi will **NOT** take your CSV data in `$whereVtest1` and split it up for you. You have to EXPLICITLY provide a *SINGLE* value for EVERY placeholder you have:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, 'ss....s', $val1, $val2, .... $valN);
                                ^----------^
                                 ^------------------^
                                      ^------------------------^
```

Comment: A HUGE thank you for the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You have two wrong factors:

1. Your `$whereVtest1 = "$lc_postcode, $proptype";` is a `string` as it is encapsulated in quotes. The variables (2) are printed into the string. so in effect this variable is just one variable, it is *NOT* two or more concatenated (which it looks like you where trying to do).

You can not concatenate variables like this, use an array if required.

2. `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "ss", $whereVtest1);` this is telling SQL to expect *TWO* *string* values (`ss`), but due to *(1)* you are giving it just one. This is your error.

To fix:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "ss", $lc_postcode, $proptype);
```

This line will now work and marry up the PHP and SQL correctly.

---

Edit: As mentioned by [scaisEdge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39625266/3536236) you also need to ensure your comment sections are correctly closed.

Comment: A HUGE thank you for the correct answer. Also, thank you for alluding to an array. I may also follow that up.

Comment: I have accepted Marc B's answer simply because it came first. Yours is every bit as good.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the close comment in the code.  try adding */

```
/* 1. create a prepared statement  */
                                   ^^  here
if ($stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT $what_select4TS FROM $table WHERE $where_no_andP ORDER BY rent $reihenach LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage"))
```

Comment: doesn't matter. you can have as many `/*` as you want. it'll all be a comment until a `*/` is encountered.

Comment: @MarcB  if the comment is not closed the sql instruction is not formed and the binding fails ..

Comment: ah yeah, sorry. should've looked at what was in the comment. missed the prepare call. but still. doesn't solve OP's problem. not enough values for the number of placeholders.

Comment: well ...downvote a correct answer is not fair .. anyway

Answer (score 0):

you are only binding one parameter, you have to bind the 2nd variable as well - for example:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "ss", $whereVtest1, wherePtest1);
```

Comment: Thank you for alluding to the correct answer